# Raspberry Pi camera doesn't work only displays red light

Tags: python, camera, rpi.gpio

When I run my code, I get this error:

> No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board

The red light on the camera module glows, but doesn't capture an image and instead shows the above error.

Is it only me facing this problem? Can you please help me find a solution to this problem and also explain the cause of it?

Comment: Are you using a good 2A power supply? Disable Bluetooth, WiFi and use Ethernet to see if it's a power draw problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly determine whether the issue is software (your code) or hardware (the camera module itself). After a clean boot, use the demo `raspistill` / `raspivid` commands to test the camera module. If `raspistill -o test.jpg` doesn't fire up the camera almost immediately, something's wrong with the hardware end of things (I'll assume below the issue is hardware).

There's two common(ish) hardware issues:

1. **Bad connection**: as the error message suggests this is the most common cause. Do as it says and check the camera's cable to the Pi (it should look [like this](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/quickstart.html)), and the connection for the small chip on the camera board itself (labelled "SUNNY" on the V1 modules, but usually blank on the V2 modules). The chip can be prised up fairly easily with a thumbnail and re-seated by pushing it back down again (obviously have the camera disconnected when doing this).
2. **Dead module**: the camera module is static sensitive and it's possible  that it's been damaged. I generally suggest that getting a small holder or case for the camera (even something as simple [as this](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-camera-mount)) is a worthwhile investment as it minimizes the amount you need to touch the board. Unfortunately if this is the case there's nothing you can realistically do to fix it, just get a replacement.

Comment: I've had this today :( dead module as I tried 2 wires, one on a pi-zero, one on a pi-3

Comment: If you're switching wires, make sure you've got them the [right way round](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/quickstart.html) at both ends before writing off the module.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the silver contacts are well inserted into the PCB connector. 
[(video here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GImeVqHQzsE)

Also, make sure that the sunny connector is firmly attached. 
[image: Sunny connector]

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had several issues after leaving my camera module inside the ESD bag. The contacts oxidized and I had to clean both the flat cable and the sunny connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Had this  problem for a while, turned out I had it connected to the display slot and not the camera slot. There are two slots on the Pi 4 that look identical.