# Raspberry camera is not giving any output?

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, raspbian-stretch

I am using Raspberry pi 3 Model B and Raspberry Pi Camera v2.1. When I am using a simple code to show the live video, it is neither giving any output nor any error. During the running time of code, the LED on the camera is glowing but camera is not giving any output. I am not able to find where the mistake is. I am totally depressed now. Can anyone help?
All things were working properly. I was in my project presentation room and I have left my project for half an hour and when I came back camera was not working. I don't know what had happened with my camera, please help.

 I have checked it with another camera and another Pi too but same thing.

Output of

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

is

```
supported=1 detected=1
```

Comment: You might want to share your code with us so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running some of the demo code for the Pi camera?

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

That might be a good way to isolate whether the problem is your code or the hardware.

If you have a spare SD card handy, you could also try to image a fresh Raspbian install to rule out any environment settings to help better determine if this a hardware or software problem. A quick search turned up a similar issue with some good troubleshooting steps from about a year ago. They seem like a solid place to start.

[Raspberry Pi camera doesn't work only displays red light](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/68443/39843)

If you want to share your code, myself or others could help troubleshoot there.